Implement an external webcam on react native app
I need to create a React native app that allows to take picture with an external webcam (AXIS M1014). I think it can be done with rtsp but i don't know how to implemente it. Do you have any ideas ?
I have created an App that uses the android camera, but I need to use an external webcam.

You can use exoplayer to do RTSP.
Add Library
implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-rtsp:1.4.1")

Use exoplayer in code
val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
// Set the media item to be played.
player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(rtspUri))
// Prepare the player.
player.prepare()

Refer https://developer.android.com/media/media3/exoplayer/rtsp
